# How to read mulitple texfiles in a folder and store each text file in an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, directory

i want to store the text in the textfiles in a string array and traverse it to a data grid view table. Is there any way i can do that

```
 private string[] textfiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\UPLOADS", "*.txt")
                                 .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                 .ToArray();
```

i used the above method to get the text files.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < excelfiles.Length; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(i, excelfiles[i], File.ReadAllText(textfiles[i]) , "24/12/16", "3.42pm", 837482, "Approve / Reject");
        }
```

however i am gettting the following error.

`Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\[2016-12-30] lololololol.xlsm(desc).txt'.`

My path is stated is D:\UPLOADS

here is the full code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private string[] excelfiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\UPLOADS", "*.xlsm")
                                 .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                 .ToArray();
    private string[] textfiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\UPLOADS", "*.txt")
                                 .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                 .ToArray();




    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ExcelID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("excelName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("excelDescription", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("time", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("empID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("firstApproval", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < excelfiles.Length; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(i, excelfiles[i], File.ReadAllText(textfiles[i]) , "24/12/16", "3.42pm", 837482, "Approve / Reject");
        }


        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes there are many ways to do it. Did you try to do something?

Comment: Pleas read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the textfiles, you trim away the path D:\UPLOADS from the full filename. So when you try to read the content of the filename you don't have any path to give to `File.ReadAllText`.

This will force the method in trying to read from the current process directory (...\IIS Express...) where there is no such file.

You need that path to retrieve your file contents, so you could remove the Linq `Select` part and leave just ....

```
 private string[] textfiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\UPLOADS", "*.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several APIs you will find relevant in this case.

`Directory.GetFiles()` returns an array of full paths to all files in a folder.

`File.ReadAllText()` returns the all contents of a file as a string.

Using these two you should be definitely able to implement your requested functionality.